# moment.js in angular is not formatting as I would expect

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-directive, angular-moment

I have a Time being pulled from a server in the following JSON format:

```
"begins_at":"2016-04-22T08:11:07.000Z"
```

I am using momentjs with angular with the following filter:

```
{{event_details.begins_at | moment: "format": "HH:MM a"}}
```

I would expect the following output: `08:11 am`.  Instead, I am getting: `04:04 am`.  I suspect it might have something to do with timezones, but I'm not sure.  How do I fix this?

Comment: moment is a js lib, not an angular filter, if you have defined a filter named `moment` that utilizes that lib then post it's code

Comment: actually angular-moment comes with built-in filters.  I didn't define anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **MM** to **mm** (months to minutes : ))

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .provider('moment', function() {  // be nice for DI
    this.$get = function() {
      return moment
    }
  })
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    this.event_details = {
      begins_at: '2016-04-22T08:11:07.000Z'
    }
  })
  .filter('moment', function(moment) {
    return function(input, options) {
      return moment(input).format(options.split('\'')[1]) // ugly formatter ; (
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl as c'>
    moment: {{ c.event_details.begins_at | moment:"format: 'HH:mm a'" }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative. JS date is an ISO Date so we just need to use moments conversion method to use JS native date formatting. This does not require you to create a custom formatter.

```
{{myMomentDate.toISOString() | date: <your angular filter>}}
```